# Check array of optionals for nil

Tags: swift

I have a number of optionals and would like to efficiently check to see if any of them is nil.

Ideally...

```
if contains([optional1, optional2, optional3], nil) { /* foo */ }
```

But swift won't let me do this. *(Type 'S.Generator.Element -> L' does not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible')*

And optionals can't be AnyObjects so I can't cast it to an NSArray either (to use .containsObject).

I could just write a for loop but that seems like bad style. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why is a for-loop bad style?

Comment: Because logically speaking, I'm not trying to manipulate or perform any action with the objects in my array. I just want to know *IF* any of them is nil. A for loop can get the job done, but it's not an accurate expression of what I actually want to do. I know, I'm picky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two `contains()` functions:

```
func contains<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element : Equatable>(seq: S, x: S.Generator.Element) -> Bool
func contains<S : SequenceType, L : BooleanType>(seq: S, predicate: @noescape (S.Generator.Element) -> L) -> Bool
```

The first one takes an *element* as the second argument, but
requires that the elements conform to the `Equatable`
protocol, which is not the case for optionals.

The second one takes a *predicate* as second argument, and that
can be used here:

```
let optArray : [Int?] = [1, nil, 2]
if contains(optArray, { $0 == nil } ) {

}
```

But any solution must traverse the array until a `nil` element is
found, so the above solution may be better readable but is not
necessarily *more efficient* than a for-loop.